# Migrate TortoiseSVN repo to Bitbucket with all revisions

Tags: git, svn

My company just decided to use JIRA software. My boss also agreed to use Bitbucket which I am trying to configure as of now.

At this moment we are using Tortoise SVN, we have atleast 3000 revisions, which we certainly do not want to lose! I already googled and searched the atlassian-support website but I just can't find out what I have to do in our current situation. Does anybody have any experience with this migration without losing any versions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like [git svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) and [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/).

If you have a lot of "tags" (Subversion doesn't really have tags) and branches you probably also want to preserve them. There are a lot of [instructions](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=git+svn+convert+branches+tags) out there, mostly about `git svn`; reposurgeon has its own detailed [guide](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/dvcs-migration-guide.html).

In short:

- You collect committers' logins/names/emails and prepare a file with a mapping from SVN logins to names and emails of committers.
- You run `git svn clone`. You need access to SVN server; TortoiseGit is irrelevant here as it's an SVN client; reposurgeon can work on the result of `svnadmin dump` but the dump must be performed on server.
- You fix branches and tags in the cloned git repo.

I have my own [scripts](http://git.phdru.name/?p=git-scripts.git;a=tree;f=svn;hb=HEAD) and an example of "authors.txt" file. I must admit I didn't use them since 2014 — I converted all my repos and forgot about Subversion.

Comment: Today I don't have the possibility to check it out, I will tommorow. Will accept then.